# trying to get the (new) topbar fixed

Tags: support

Since the Stack Exchange redesign, I try to reestablish that my topbar is fixed; but I can´t seem to get it right; and I can´t think of anything else than

```
@-moz-document domain(stackexchange.com) {
    .top-bar { position:fixed }
}
```

in `userContent.css`, but that has no effect.

Any idea how I can keep the main navigational element on PPCG always in sight?

Comment: `.top-bar { position:fixed }` seems to work for me if added in a stylish script so your problem must be the inclusion of that in the page

Comment: I haven't tried this, but the page styles will override `userContent.css` unless you add `!important`.

Comment: "Since we got our own design" wait what

Comment: I don´t know, why it did not work; but `!important` did not help. And I don´t know why it works now. I thought it may have helped that `_fixed` was added to the topbar´s classes; but there is no `fixed` whatsoever on `softwareengineering` ... yet _my_ topbar there is also fixed.